# calculating probability distribution function of double integral moment

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, factorial, moment-generating-functions

When k th moment is as followed, what would be the probability distribution function of X? (k=0, 1, 2...)
$$E[X^k]=(2k+1)!!$$

I thought about central normal distribution's moment, but couldn't think of ways to apply it to this question.

Comment: Do !! mean the factorial of the factorial?

Comment: @zoli sorry for the lack of information. It means double integral, $(2k+1)!!=\frac{(2k+1)!}{k!2^k}$

Comment: It is chi-square distribution with 3 degrees of freedom.